# colorize bash_completion

Tags: bash, colors

When I type `grep` and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice, `bash_completion` will list files and directories in current directory. It will also complete filenames when I type initial letter. That is all very nice, the only problem is that when the directory contains many files and subdirectories, it can be quite chaotic and disorganized.

It would help very much if `bash_completion` could at least color directories differently, similarly to what `ls -lA` does.

Is this possible?

### EDIT:

this is what my sample `bash_completion` config file looks like:

```
if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
    return 0

else
    _filedir
fi
```

Comment: I don't know if this is possible in `bash` but it is the default behavior in `zsh`.

Comment: in case it is not obvious, I am looking for a solution for `bash`

Comment: What file are you showing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no out of the box feature like this in the current version of Bash, you can do this using `zsh`, it's there by default.

One of the tools related to the completion is called `compgen`. You can finagle it to show commands correctly colorized, but this is a hack and not that practically useful.

```
$ compgen -W "$(ls --color=always *)"
```

That will properly list the files out colorized, but it's getting the color from `ls`, so I wouldn't consider this native coloring by `auto_completion`.

#### References

- [Bash - colored tab completion?](https://superuser.com/questions/251107/bash-colored-tab-completion)
- [misc: compgen, colors, comp interruption](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/bQhEyPtjtYTrfOhvOUSC)

Comment: please see my edit. I don't have any `ls` in my `bash_completion` config files. Looks like there is a function `_filedir` which lists files.